How to tell if a function is wrapped by another specific function
Using the following code:
def wrap( x ):
  def wrapped( y ):
    return x + y
  return wrapped

f = wrap( 1 )

Is it possible to tell that f is a function wrapped by function wrap?
Displaying variable f, it is visible:
>>> f
<function wrap.<locals>.wrapped at 0x10067cf40>

But is there a way to know sure that wrap was used as the wrapping function?

It shouldn't really be relevant.  If I say xxxx = wrap, f = xxxx( 1 ), the functionality is identical, but would you want to find out xxxx or wrap?

@TimRoberts - I'm using the wrapped function as a parameter to a function, and inside this other function I'd like to know whether the function is wrapped or not to slightly alter how the parameter is used. One possibility is to try and use the function in a try...except block and see if it behaves as expected (ask for forgiveness rather than permission), but was curious to know if it's possible to know if a function was wrapped by a specific function.

"I'd like to know whether the function is wrapped or not to slightly alter how the parameter is used" - that sounds like a bad move. It's coupling these parts of your program in a bizarre, fragile way that will make refactoring very awkward, and interact very poorly with decorators. You should find a different way to approach your underlying goal.

You have received a couple of answers here, but as with MANY things in Python, just because it's possible does not mean that it's a good idea.  You're calling it a "wrapped function" as if that were a thing, but it's not.  This is just a function object that is a local variable being returned.

You really should not change your behaviour in response to whether a function is wrapped or not. Callers will generally expect that they can substitute a function with a decorated or wrapped one freely; changing the behaviour of your function in response will lead to hard-to-debug problems. If we understood why you feel you need to discriminate between “wrapped” and “unwrapped” functions, we might be able to suggest a better approach.

Python functions have a __closure__ property that is None if the function doesn’t close over any values. wrapped will have a tuple of cells (for the closed-over x) but wrapper will have None.
Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-read-only-attributes

more or less - a wrapped function that uses no variables from the enclosing function won't have __closure__ set, and it will be None all the same.

This works, but I'm wondering if there is a more pythonic (or proper) way:
>>> f.__qualname__
'wrap.<locals>.wrapped'
>>> hasattr( f, '__qualname__') and f.__qualname__.startswith('wrap.')
True
>>>


yes - __qualname__ is where this information is available. The wrapping function only shows as a string, but combining that with f.__module__, which has the module name, one can assert the wrapping.  A non-string information about a wrapped function can be checked in its  __closure__ attribute: while it can assert the function was created in a nested-function context if its not None, it is only set if the nonlocal variables from the wrapping function are used, and there are no links that can be introspected going from the __closure__ to the wrapping function anyway.
